# Where does Joomla stores the session handler setting?

Tags: component, database, joomla-1.5, session

I have recently changed the Session Handler setting in Joomla 1.5! from 'database' to 'none'. I am searching as to where does Joomla! stores this information in the DB.

To be more precise, where does Joomla! saves the setting of Session Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting is stored in the configuration file `configuration.php` (located in the root folder of your Joomla installation) under the `$session_handler` variable. By default it is:

```
public $session_handler = 'database';
```